# attempt to perform arithmetic (mul) on a number and nil

Tags: lua, roblox

So, im making a camera from rake classic (roblox), and the camera keeps getting this error, so heres the code

```lua
v66 = p11 * l__CFrame_fromAxisAngle__4(l__Vector3_new__1(l__unit__64.y, -l__unit__64.x, 0), l__math_acos__2(-l__z__65) * (p13 and 1)) or p11;
```

i tried nothing but here

and the result was still that same error, attempt to perform arithmetic (mul) on a number and nil

Comment: You are doing a lot in 1 line of code, if you break this up into multiple lines it will be easier to debug your problem

Comment: `(p13 and 1)`  this can evaluate to false and nil, matching the error message

Comment: This is synapse x obfuscated code, I'd suggest not using stolen code in your games.